# JMeter : determine number of threads per second

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

How can i configure the Jmeter to run for only one second and in the results i can see how many requests executed within this second.

I tried Constant Throughput Timer and also tried scheduler on thread croup level but failed to reach my needs.

Any idea?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting lives in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) itself:

[image]

In this case JMeter will run 1 thread for 1 second and will try to execute as many requests as it can during this time frame.

With Constant Throughput Timer you can only **pause** JMeter throughput (number of requests per minute) to the desired rate but it works precisely enough on **minute** level, if you need second-level precision - consider going for [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitri T , I don't have "Specify Thread lifetime" as your screenshot. I am using v.5.0

Comment: In JMeter 5.0 it was called **Duration**. In general [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3) (or whatever is the [latest stable JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) as soon as possible)

Comment: I downloaded v.5.3 and configured the requests but Jmeter not stopped if one second is passed and number of threads not done. My target that i need to know my service can handle how many requests in one second.

Comment: It means that your requests take longer than 1 second, if you want to continue with your weird requirement of 1-second-load-test-run consider defining response timeout of 1000 milliseconds, it can be set on "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults). Normally you should allow your test to last longer, increase the load gradually, have some "plateau" period, decrease the load gradually, and look into i.e. [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listener output.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitri T for your support